# Question about inductive step when constructing a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Theorem: For any sequence $\{p_n\}$ in a compact metric space $X$, some subsequence of $\{p_n\}$
> converges to some point $p \in X$.

If the range of $\{p_n\}$ is infinite, it must have a limit point $p \in X$. We want to construct some $\{p_{n_k}\}$ that converges to $p$. If we are at all able to construct this subsequence, then $p$ is guaranteed to be the limit of this subsequence.

Now consider $N_1(p)$. Since this neighborhood contains an infinite number of points of $\{p_n\}$, we can  choose an element and label it $p_{n_1}$. Suppose $N_{\frac 1k}(p)$ contains the points $p_{n_1}, p_{n_2}, \ldots, p_{n_i}$ with $n_j < n_{j + 1}$. Since $N_{\frac {1}{i+1}}(p)$ contains infinite number of points of $\{p_n\}$, we have that $p_{n_{i + i}} \in N_{\frac {1}{i+1}}(p)$. My question is How do we know $n_i < n_{i + 1}?$

Comment: There are an infinite number of points of $\{p_n\}$ in $N_{\frac {1}{i+1}}(p)$ that we can choose from. They cannot all have an index smaller than $n_i$, so we can just choose one with a larger index.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, Suppose $n_i \ge n_{i + 1}.$ Then $p_{n_{i + 1}}$ is one of $p_{n_1}, p_{n_2}, \ldots, p_{n_i}$ in which case  $p_{n_{i + i}} \not \in N_{\frac {1}{i+1}}(p)$. Correct?

Comment: No. We have a list of points $p_1, p_2, p_3,...$ with a limit point $p$. We want to pick out some subsequence such that the ones we pick converge to $p$. Suppose, we have picked $p_{10}, p_{132}, p_{452}$ so far, the last being within a distance of $1/3$ to $p$. There are infinitely many points $p_k$ closer than $1/4$ to $p$, so we can simply choose one with an index larger than $452$. It could very well be that $p_{321}$ is also closer than $1/4$ to $p$, but it does not matter because we can just ignore $p_1,...,p_{452}$ and pick our fourth point from the remaining set $\{p_k | k>452\}$.

Comment: "If the range of $\{p_n\}$ is infinite, it must have a limit point $p\in X$." - Do you have a theorem available that says this? It may be part of what you are supposed to prove.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, yes, I have the following theorem: https://ibb.co/mNd0NsF